# Remove a single Special Character from a String

Tags: c#, replace

I am new to C# and I want to know that how can I remove a single apostrophe ( `'` ) from my string. I have a problem that I am using my code to remove other special characters and it works fine except this special character ( `'` ).

My code is:

```
mystring=mystring.Replace(@"'"," ");
```

How can i remove this character from my string is there any other way can anybody please help me?

Comment: Your code should work as-is.  Something else is wrong.  Are you sure it's that character and not one of the "stylized" apostropes like `?

Comment: You shouldn't do that in the first place.  Instead, use parameters / escaping so that apostrophes work correctly.

Comment: Also, use @ for escaping string literals

Comment: it is like ( ’ ) this is the special character i have copied from source

Comment: @user3154778: That is not a regular apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a regular apostrophe.

You need something more like this.

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\x92", "");
```

Comment: it works like a charm can you please tell me how it is done? so that i can keep in mind? please

Comment: The character you are replacing is not a standard keyboard character. It's the character with hexadecimal value 0x92. You can specify such a character in a string constants using `\x92`. You could also paste the character exactly into the string in your source code. But I don't like that because someone else could get confused like you were. My code above is a bit more obvious about which character is being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

The character you are showing us in the comment is another one than the one you are using in the code

```
(’)     => is ANSI 146  (in comment, 92 hex) 

(')     => is ANSI  39  (in code)
```

Solution 1: Copy paste the character from the source into the code.

Solution 2: Use a unicode escape sequence:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\u0092", " ");
```

or, using chars instead of strings:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace('\u0092', ' ');
```

Note, in your example you are replacing the apostrophe by a space. If you want to remove it instead do:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\u0092", "");
```

See: [ANSI character set and equivalent Unicode and HTML characters](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html).

Comment: I can give you +1 for sure you sir deserve this but somebody made my question -1 sad

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Regex.Replace method

```
string output = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"'", "");
```

I hope I helped

Comment: An apostrophe is not an escape character.

Comment: so what's the solution how can i remove it?

Comment: the string output is your initial string(mystring) with the "'" replaced. Isn't it what you want? or did i misread the question? :x I hope this is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

//we can remove . or any special character from string using Replace in csharp//

```
string name = " .Akhil. ";
 name = name.Replace( " .Akhil. ", "Akhil");
Console.WriteLine(name);
```